# Web scraping and design pattern lifting

Tags: python, design-patterns, web-scraping, python-requests

I would like to get some feed back on my code; the goal is to get all agencies address of banks. I wrote a pretty simple brute force algorithm.
I was wondering if you would have any advice to improve the code, design it differently (do I need an OOP approach here) etc .

````
import requests
from lxml import html

groupe = "credit-agricole"
dep = '21'
groupes =["credit-agricole"]
deps = ['53', '44', '56', '35', '22', '49', '72', '29', '85']

def get_nb_pages(groupe,dep):
    """ Return nb_pages ([int]): number of pages containing banks information .
    Args:
        groupe ([string]): bank groupe ("credit-agricole",...)
        dep ([string]): departement ("01",...)
    """
    url ="https://www.moneyvox.fr/pratique/agences/{groupe}/{dep}".format(groupe=groupe,dep=dep)
    req = requests.get(url)
    raw_html = req.text
    xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/article/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/nav/a"
    tree = html.fromstring(raw_html)
    nb_pages = len(tree.xpath(xpath)) +1
    
    return nb_pages

def get_agencies(groupe,dep,page_num):
    """ Return agencies ([List]): description of agencies scrapped on website target page.
    Args:
        groupe ([string]): bank groupe ("credit-agricole",...)
        dep ([string]): departement ("01",...)
        page_num ([int]): target page
    """
    url ="https://www.moneyvox.fr/pratique/agences/{groupe}/{dep}/{page_num}".format(groupe=groupe,dep=dep,page_num=page_num)
    req = requests.get(url)
    raw_html = req.text
    xpath = '//div[@class="lh-bloc-agence like-text"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(raw_html)
    blocs_agencies = tree.xpath(xpath)
    agencies = [] 
    for bloc in  blocs_agencies:
        agence = bloc.xpath("div/div[1]/h4")[0].text
        rue = bloc.xpath("div/div[1]/p[1]")[0].text
        code_postale = bloc.xpath("div/div[1]/p[2]")[0].text
        agencies.append((agence,rue,code_postale))
    return agencies
    
def get_all(groupes,deps):
    """Return all_agencies ([List]): description of agencies scrapped.
    Args:
        groupes ([List]): target groups
        deps ([List]): target departments
    """
    all_agencies = []
    for groupe in groupes:
        for dep in deps:
            nb_pages = get_nb_pages(groupe,dep)
            for p in range(1,nb_pages+1):
                agencies = get_agencies(groupe,dep,p)
                all_agencies.extend(agencies)   
    df_agencies = pd.DataFrame(all_agencies,columns=['agence','rue','code_postale'])
    return df_agencies
    


get_nb_pages(groupe,dep)
get_agencies(groupe,dep,1)
df_agencies = get_all(groupes,deps)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

- It's fine for your strings - and scraped web content - to be localised in French; but ensure that your variables are in English (groupe -> group) for consistency
- Prefer tuples over lists when you have immutable data
- Add PEP484 type hints when possible
- Do not leave those first four variables in global scope; move them to a function
- Consider using f-strings instead of `format` calls
- Always check to see if your `requests` calls fail; the easiest way is via `raise_for_status`
- Tell `requests` when you're done with a response via context management
- Use actual integers for your department numbers instead of stringly-typed data
- Consider using an intermediate dataclass for your agency data instead of implicit tuples
- Consider using generator functions (`yield`) to simplify your iterative code

### First Suggested

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
from typing import Iterable, Collection

import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml.html import HtmlElement


@dataclass
class Agency:
    name: str
    street: str
    postal_code: str

    @classmethod
    def from_block(cls, block: HtmlElement) -> 'Agency':
        return cls(
            name=block.xpath("div/div[1]/h4")[0].text,
            street=block.xpath("div/div[1]/p[1]")[0].text,
            postal_code=block.xpath("div/div[1]/p[2]")[0].text,
        )


def get_nb_pages(group: str, department: int) -> int:
    """ Return nb_pages ([int]): number of pages containing banks information .
    Args:
        groupe ([string]): bank groupe ("credit-agricole",...)
        department ([string]): departement ("01",...)
    """
    url = f"https://www.moneyvox.fr/pratique/agences/{group}/{department}"
    with requests.get(url) as req:
        req.raise_for_status()
        raw_html = req.text

    xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/article/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/nav/a"
    tree = html.fromstring(raw_html)
    return len(tree.xpath(xpath)) + 1


def get_agencies(group: str, department: int, page_num: int) -> Iterable[Agency]:
    """ Return agencies ([List]): description of agencies scrapped on website target page.
    Args:
        groupe ([string]): bank groupe ("credit-agricole",...)
        department ([string]): departement ("01",...)
        page_num ([int]): target page
    """
    url = f"https://www.moneyvox.fr/pratique/agences/{group}/{department}/{page_num}"
    with requests.get(url) as req:
        req.raise_for_status()
        raw_html = req.text

    xpath = '//div[@class="lh-bloc-agence like-text"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(raw_html)
    for block in tree.xpath(xpath):
        yield Agency.from_block(block)


def get_all(groups: Iterable[str], departments: Collection[int]):
    """Return all_agencies ([List]): description of agencies scrapped.
    Args:
        groupes ([List]): target groups
        departments ([List]): target departments
    """
    for group in groups:
        for department in departments:
            nb_pages = get_nb_pages(group, department)
            for page in range(1, nb_pages + 1):
                yield from get_agencies(group, department, page)


def main():
    group = "credit-agricole"
    department = 21
    groups = ("credit-agricole",)
    departments = (53, 44,)  # ...  56, 35, 22, 49, 72, 29, 85)

    n_pages = get_nb_pages(group, department)
    agencies = tuple(get_agencies(group, department, page_num=1))

    all_agencies = get_all(groups, departments)
    df_agencies = pd.DataFrame(
        (astuple(agency) for agency in all_agencies),
        columns=('agence', 'rue', 'code_postale'),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All of that being the case, your approach using xpath selectors is very fragile. Here is an alternate approach that uses named elements with classes and IDs where available. It is incomplete because I think the site rate-limited my IP, which is of course a direct risk of scraping and totally within the rights of the website.

### BeautifulSoup Alternate

```
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
from typing import Iterable, Dict, ClassVar, Pattern
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

import pandas as pd
from requests import Session

ROOT = 'https://www.moneyvox.fr'


@dataclass
class Branch:
    name: str
    street: str
    city: str
    postal_code: str
    path: str

    @classmethod
    def scrape_all(cls, session: Session, path: str) -> Iterable['Branch']:
        page = ''
        while True:
            with session.get(ROOT + path + page) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')

            body = doc.select_one('div.main-body')
            city = None

            for head_or_cell in body.select('h2, div.lh-bloc-agence'):
                if head_or_cell.name == 'h2':
                    city = head_or_cell.text
                elif head_or_cell.name == 'div':
                    street, postal_code = head_or_cell.select('p')
                    yield cls(
                        name=head_or_cell.h4.text,
                        street=street.text,
                        city=city,
                        postal_code=postal_code.text,
                        path=head_or_cell.select_one('a.lh-btn-info')['href'],
                    )

            # perform depagination here


@dataclass
class Department:
    name: str
    code: str
    path: str
    n_branches: int

    re_count: ClassVar[Pattern] = re.compile(r'\d+')

    @classmethod
    def from_li(cls, li: Tag) -> 'Department':
        return cls(
            name=li.strong.text,
            path=li.a['href'],
            code=cls.re_count.search(li.a.text)[0],
            n_branches=int(cls.re_count.search(li.em.text)[0]),
        )


@dataclass
class Agency:
    name: str
    category: str
    path: str

    @classmethod
    def scrape_all(cls, session: Session) -> Iterable['Agency']:
        with session.get(ROOT + '/pratique/agences') as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')

        body = doc.select_one('div.main-body')
        category = None
        for head_or_cell in body.select('h2, a.lh-lien-bloc-liste'):
            if head_or_cell.name == 'h2':
                category = head_or_cell.text
            elif head_or_cell.name == 'a':
                yield cls(
                    name=head_or_cell.text,
                    category=category,
                    path=head_or_cell['href'],
                )

    def get_departments(self, session: Session) -> Dict[str, int]:
        with session.get(ROOT + self.path) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')

        for li in doc.select('#tabs-departement li'):
            yield Department.from_li(li)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def main():
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.width', None)

    with Session() as session:
        agencies = {a.name: a for a in Agency.scrape_all(session)}
        agency_df = pd.DataFrame(
            (astuple(a) for a in agencies.values()),
            columns=('Nom', 'Catégorie', 'Lien'),
        )
        print(agency_df)

        agency = agencies['Crédit Agricole']
        departments = {d.name: d for d in agency.get_departments(session)}

        department = departments['Ardennes']
        branches = {b.name: b for b in Branch.scrape_all(session, department.path)}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize what Reinderien already said, always check the return of your calls to requests. `status_code` should return 200. If you get anything else you should stop and investigate. It is possible that the website is blocking you and there is no point running blind.

Also, I recommend that you **spoof the user agent**, otherwise it is obvious to the web server that you are running a **bot** and they may block you, or apply more stringent rate limiting measures than a casual user would experience. By default the user agent would be something like this: python-requests/2.25.1.

And since you are making repeated calls, you should use a [session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) instead. Reinderien already refactored your code with session but did not mention this point explicitly. The benefits are persistence (when using cookies for instance) and also more efficient connection pooling at TCP level. And you can use session to set default headers for all your requests.

Example:

```
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> session.headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
>>>
```

Change the user agent for the session, here we spoof Firefox:

```
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'})
```

And then you can use session.get to retrieve pages.

May you could be interested in **prepared queries** too. I strongly recommend that Python developers get acquainted with that section of the documentation.

To speed up the process you could also add parallel processing, for example using threads. But be gentle, if you have too many open connections at the same time, it is one thing that can get you blocked. Usage patterns have to remain reasonable and human-like.